# how to adjust a numeric vector in order to force its sum to be equal to 1L?

Tags: r, math

vec = c(1.349667e-04,1.969667e-04,4.866497e-02,6.196667e-05,3.560097e-02,7.796667e-05,
9.896667e-05,1.035540e-01,1.127967e-03,1.361497e-02,1.997300e-01,1.249667e-04,1.877997e-02, 1.501250e-01,2.405967e-03,1.218597e-02,1.354810e-01,2.179667e-04,2.119967e-03,9.272497e-02, 4.696667e-05,1.399667e-04,8.739897e-02,5.885497e-02,2.222497e-02,1.709667e-04,1.124497e-02, 2.441967e-03,4.049667e-04,4.196667e-05)

```
> sum(vec)
[1] 1
> sum(vec)==1L
[1] FALSE
```

How can I slightly adjust each value of this vector so it sums to 1L?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
> sum(vec/sum(vec))==1L
[1] TRUE
```

And you should read [FAQ 7.31](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html).